# How validate v-text-fields inside dynamic array by index id with vuelidate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate

I wrote a dynamic form (pressing an add button adds 1 text field every time) and the problem is, that if i validate with my function the textfield, ALL the same dynamic textfields response if i make a mistake in any one of them... For example: if i have 5 amount text fields and i click on the first and let it empty, ALL 5 are displaying the same error  ... I wanna validate every time every text field by index with vuelidate. Is that possible ? Thank you for your answers !!!

```
 <ul v-for="(records, index) in records" :key="index">

     <!-- After each add button press, this textfield gonna be added into the form -->

      <td>
        <v-text-field
          v-model="records.amount"
          :error-messages="amountErrors"
          :counter="5"
          label="Amount"
          required    
          @input="$v.amount.$touch()"
          @blur="$v.amount.$touch()"
         ></v-text-field>
       </td>
      </ul>

     <script>

       // importing vuelidate for validation

       import { validationMixin } from "vuelidate";
       import { required } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";

       export default {
       data() {
         return {
           records: [
             {
               amount: ""
             }
           ]
         };
        },
         validations: {
            amount: { required }
         },
         computed: { 
           amountErrors() {
              const errors = [];

              if (!this.$v.amount.$dirty) {
                return errors;
              }

              if (!this.$v.amount.required) {
              // -----> if i don't type anything in the first text field 
                       // and have for example 5 textfields, ALL 5 textfield 
                       // display the same error ... is it 
                       // possible to pass here the INDEX of 
                       // each amount text field, so that 
                       // the validator knows that "ok now 
                       // i validate the first amount text 
                       // field of the array"  ???


                errors.push("Amount is required");
                return errors;
              }
          }
       }

     </script>
```